# How do I find the DNS name of a physical Hyper-V server using remote WMIC commands? I only know the virtual servers' DNS names

Tags: windows, dns, hyper-v, wmic, hypervisor

I want to identify the underlying, physical Hyper-V server (e.g., hypervisor) by DNS name of a given guest OS. I log into various virtual servers regularly.  I've read that there is a way with PowerShell (a command to find the hypervisor that supports a given VM).  But I don't want to use PowerShell.  Ideally I would use WMIC commands remotely.  But alternatively I could log in and issue WMIC command locally.  Or maybe use DOS commands.  Ideally the solution would be a one-step process.

The guest operating systems are Windows Server 2003.

Comment: I am little bit confused. So you want to find out DNS name of underlying physical machine after you logged in to guest OS? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Maybe.  I want to know the DNS name of the physical server with Hyper-V when I log into one of its virtual machines.  I regularly log into virtual servers.  I know their DNS names (obviously).  But I don't know the physical server's DNS name that supports the virtual servers.  Is that clear?

Answer (score 0):

The following registry key contains information about the Host server:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters
```

Some important keys are:

```
HostName
PhysicalHostName
PhysicalHostNameFullyQualified
VirtualMachineName
```

Plus a number of settings about the Host Server’s version

So simplest way to get host server name is to run following DOS command:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters\" /v "PhysicalHostNameFullyQualified"
```

As per my info, this works for *many* guest OS. However not sure for all. Also it needs vmtools to be installed on guest OS.

Alternatively you can issue WMI command:

```
WMIC /namespace:\\root\virtualization PATH "Msvm_ComputerSystem" Get ElementName, Caption
```

This should give you "Hosting Computer System".

Please let me know if this helps. And if yes, please don't forget to mark this as answer.

Comment: I'm not going to be able to install vmtools on the servers.  I tried that WMI command.  Unfortunately, it didn't work.  I got this <bom>: ERROR: Code = 0x8004100e   Description = Invalid namespace    Facility = WMI. <eom> Was I supposed to change the command?

Comment: The viewing of registry keys works for Windows Server 2003.  On Windows 7, I cannot say if it works or not.  But manually drilling into the registry for informational purposes can be a last resort.  I'd prefer the WMIC command method because I could script it or automate it.  I hope someone knows why the WMIC command didn't work.

Comment: Try running DOS command I given. It fetches info from registry only.